# how to make search bar to move up and hide while scroll in table view?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

I had tried just to show and hide while scrolling table view images but here I need like when I start scroll the table view the search bar also needs to go to top and hide and when ever I scroll down the search bar need to come down along with table view scroll and fix on the same position can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Here is my code which already tried for detecting scroll when table view scrolls

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        if(velocity.y>0) {
            //Code will work without the animation block.I am using animation block incase if you want to set any delay to it.
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {
                self.searchBar.isHidden = true
                print("Hide")
            }, completion: nil)

        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {
                self.searchBar.isHidden = false
                print("Unhide")
            }, completion: nil)    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

simple drag search bar into tableview.

Comment: no I need to have search bar on top of table view images like shown here

Comment: drag search bar to tablview cell. it will join top of the tablview cell.

Comment: and yes search bar scroll with tableview.

Comment: but I am having lot of images if I place on cell then it will display on all cells  according to your idea is it not ?